# libnfc: unable to open NFC device

Tags: nfc

I have a problem with libnfc on a Raspberry Pi 3B trying to read data from a PN532 card reader. I installed libnfc as the official site suggest to do and in fact it all worked this morning. I was able to detect my device using the `nfc-list` and `nfc-scan-device` commands.

Then I tried to run a C program (not done by me, but done by a person here in the company) and it worked. Did it again and it didn't work, but returned an error.
Tried to run the nfc-list command and it returned the same error. Since then, it looks like the libnfc library stopped working properly.

These are the errors I get when I try to run some commands:

`nfc-list`:

```
nfc-list uses libnfc 1.7.1
error   libnfc.bus.i2c  Error: wrote only -1 bytes (10 expected).
error   libnfc.driver.pn532_i2c Unable to transmit data. (TX)
pn53x_check_communication: Input / Output Error
error   libnfc.bus.i2c  Error: wrote only -1 bytes (10 expected).
error   libnfc.driver.pn532_i2c Unable to transmit data. (TX)
nfc-list: ERROR: Unable to open NFC device: pn532_i2c:/dev/i2c-1
```

`nfc-scan-device -v`:

```
nfc-scan-device uses libnfc 1.7.1
1 NFC device(s) found:
error   libnfc.bus.i2c  Error: wrote only -1 bytes (10 expected).
error   libnfc.driver.pn532_i2c Unable to transmit data. (TX)
pn53x_check_communication: Input / Output Error
error   libnfc.bus.i2c  Error: wrote only -1 bytes (10 expected).
error   libnfc.driver.pn532_i2c Unable to transmit data. (TX)
nfc_open failed for pn532_i2c:/dev/i2c-1
```

`LIBNFC_LOG_LEVEL=3 nfc-list`:

```
debug   libnfc.config   key: [device.name], value: [PN532 over I2C]
debug   libnfc.config   key: [device.connstring], value: [pn532_i2c:/dev/i2c-1]
debug   libnfc.config   Unable to open directory: /etc/nfc/devices.d
debug   libnfc.general  log_level is set to 3
debug   libnfc.general  allow_autoscan is set to true
debug   libnfc.general  allow_intrusive_scan is set to false
debug   libnfc.general  1 device(s) defined by user
debug   libnfc.general    #0 name: "PN532 over I2C", connstring: "pn532_i2c:/dev/i2c-1"
nfc-list uses libnfc 1.7.1
debug   libnfc.general  0 device(s) found using acr122_usb driver
debug   libnfc.general  0 device(s) found using pn53x_usb driver
debug   libnfc.chip.pn53x   Diagnose
debug   libnfc.chip.pn53x   Timeout value: 500
debug   libnfc.chip.pn53x   SAMConfiguration
debug   libnfc.chip.pn53x   Timeout value: 1000
debug   libnfc.bus.i2c  TX: 00 00 ff 03 fd d4 14 01 17 00
error   libnfc.bus.i2c  Error: wrote only -1 bytes (10 expected).
error   libnfc.driver.pn532_i2c Unable to transmit data. (TX)
pn53x_check_communication: Input / Output Error
debug   libnfc.chip.pn53x   InRelease
debug   libnfc.bus.i2c  TX: 00 00 ff 03 fd d4 52 00 da 00
error   libnfc.bus.i2c  Error: wrote only -1 bytes (10 expected).
error   libnfc.driver.pn532_i2c Unable to transmit data. (TX)
debug   libnfc.general  Unable to open "pn532_i2c:/dev/i2c-1".
nfc-list: ERROR: Unable to open NFC device: pn532_i2c:/dev/i2c-1
```

Searched a lot but didn't find anything useful.
Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I have faced a similar problem and I was not able to read the instructions properly. ;-) 
If you have [this](http://wiki.sunfounder.cc/index.php?title=PN532_NFC_RFID_Module) device, then please keep in mind, that you have configured the jumpers properly. Due to your logs you are using i2c, this means, that you must switch jumper "1" to "on" and jumper "2" to "off". In case you have not done that, you must reboot (poweroff) your pi.